# Picking up food object in radius

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm making a Genetic Algorithm for a school project. Currently I'm building the foundation for the "dot" objects that move around and pick up food. I wrote some code that I thought should be able to do that and after some trial and error I came up with this. ( It's probably not the cleanest code and I would love to hear some tips about that as well). The only problem with the code is that the object does not just pick up 1 food but multiple and I don't know why.

> I've tried putting the food objects index in a seperate Array so I can later remove it from the food Array (when I know the index to remove >> `targetIndex`)

```
checkForTarget() {
    let inRange = new Array();
    let indexArray = new Array();
    for (let i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
        let d = dist(food[i].pos.x, food[i].pos.y, this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
        if (d < this.sense) {
            inRange.push(food[i]);
            indexArray.push(i);
        }
    }

    if (!inRange.length == 0) {
        let closest = this.sense; // this.sense = radius
        let target, targetIndex;

        for (let i = 0; i < inRange.length; i++) {
            let d = dist(inRange[i].pos.x, inRange[i].pos.y, this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
            if (d < closest) {
                target = inRange[i];
                targetIndex = indexArray[i];
                closest = d;
            }
        }

        let targetpos = createVector(target.pos.x, target.pos.y); //fixed food removing from function (resetting position by using sub)
        let desired = targetpos.sub(this.pos);
        desired.normalize();
        desired.mult(this.maxspeed);
        let steeringForce = desired.sub(this.vel);
        this.applyForce(steeringForce);

        for (let i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
            let d = dist(target.pos.x, target.pos.y, this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
            if (d < this.size) {
                console.log(targetIndex);
                this.food_eaten += 1;
                food.splice(targetIndex, 1);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

I don't get any error messages with this code, I used console.log to log the `targetIndex`. Which results in getting the same output multiple times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [...] the object does not just pick up 1 food but multiple [...]

Of course it does, becaus in

> ```js
> for (let i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
>    let d = dist(target.pos.x, target.pos.y, this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
>    if (d < this.size) {
>        // [...]
>    }
> }
> ```

The condition `d < this.size` does not depend on `food[i]`, if the condition is fulfilled it accepts each food in the array.

Just skip the `for` loop, to solve the issue. Note, you want to "eat" one food, so it is sufficient to verify if 1 food is in range. The index of the food is already identified and stored in `targetIndex`:

```js
//for (let i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {

let d = dist(target.pos.x, target.pos.y, this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
if (d < this.size) {
    console.log(targetIndex);
    this.food_eaten += 1;
    food.splice(targetIndex, 1);
}

//}
```